# Find internal surfaces in B-rep geometry

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, topology

I have a solid with internal holes. My solid is in B-rep. More exactly my solid is a list of polygons that are list of points. I want to distinguish internal surfaces from external ones. My list of polygons has a random order.

I want to be able to distinguish external surfaces from internal ones. It surely exists in literature but I can't find it.

I think BSP-trees can help me solve such a problem, but I can't find out how.

Edit:

Here is an example of my situation:
[image]

I have an idea on how to do it. My algorithm seems robust, but a bit stupid, I'm sure in literature there is something smarter :

*First I need to get a point inside my object*

- I calculate the bounding box containing my polygons
- I can then easily have a point outside if its x,y,z are superior or
  inferior to any other x,y,z of the bounding box

*Find one external face*

- From this point I do take a ray (the choice of the may be random, but
  a ray may fail to intersect the object. A ray between my exterior
  point and the center of the boundingbox should always be good)
- With ray tracing, I can find out the first polygon it touches. It may
  touch a vertex first. Then I'd just take one of the polygon that
  contains this vertex.

*Split my list of polygons into smaller lists*

Let's call P my list of polygons, and L a list of list of polygons, then l<sub>i</sub> a list of polygons included in L.
l<sub>i</sub> should include only polygons that touches each other.
Let's define what is touching each other :
We define a polygon as a list of edges.
A general definition would be that two polygons (polygon<sub>1</sub>,polygon<sub>2</sub>) touch each others if ∃(edge<sub>1</sub>,edge<sub>2</sub>)∈ polygon<sub>1</sub> x polygon<sub>2</sub>

For my simplified case : My polygons are list of points, and I know that two polygons that touches each others implies that they have a common vertex. I will use this simplified definition in practice, but it doesn't alter the methodology.

1. I take the first polygon in P
2. I remove it from P and add it to l<sub>i</sub>
3. I see if it touches any other polygon  in P
4. I get those polygons, remove them from P and add them to l<sub>i</sub>
5. I see if those polygons touch other polygons in P
6. With those newly touched polygons, I repeat the step 4. But if it didn't touch anything at step 5, I go to next step.
7. I put l<sub>i</sub> in L
8. if P still contains at least one item, I go to step 1

Only one of the sublists contain external l<sub>i</sub> the external polygon I have found above. The others are internal.
When to check which sublists contain the external polygon probably depend in the data structure, but it's a matter of optimization, not robustness.